# Pandas plot columns as index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data set with `Time`, `Name`, and `Values`. I want to plot `Time` in the x-axis, and `Values` in the y-axis, but indexed by `Name`. 
So far I did the following:

Simplified dataset:

```
     Time  Node  Value
0       0     0  64
1       0     1  54
2       0     2  80
3       0     3  50
4      10     0  62
5      10     1  53
6      10     2  76
7      10     3  47
```

Code:

```
df = df[['Time','Node','Value']]
df.plot(x='Time', y='Value')
plt.show()
```

How do I include `Node` as indexes to the values, so I have one line per node/value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The axis/columns now represent the data in a more informative way

```
df.set_index(['Time', 'Node']).unstack().plot()
```

Pay attention to the **column** and **row** headings

```
df.set_index(['Time', 'Node']).unstack()
Out[]:    
         Value            
Node     0   1   2   3
Time                  
0       64  54  80  50
10      62  53  76  47
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I have understood your question but you can try that:

```
 import seaborn as sns

 myPlot  = sns.lmplot('Time', 'Value',  data=df , hue='Node',  size = 10, fit_reg=False)

 plt.show()
```